# How to destroy reference within scope?

Tags: rust

All I was trying to do is copy a vector to another vector by iterating through it. I am getting the error `borrowed value does not live long enough`. And I get it why I am seeing this, that's because the invalid memory reference must not live outside scope. My question is, how can I destroy the reference as well in the scope after using it?

```
fn main() {
    let x: Vec<&str> = vec!["a","b","c","d"];
    let mut y: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    let z: String = String::from("xy");
    let p: &String = &z;

    for i in x {
        let k = [i, p].concat();
        let q: &str = &k;
        y.push(q);
    }

    println!("{:?}",y);
}
```

I want to keep `Vec<&str>` for `mut y`. I don't want to change it to `Vec<String>` although that's possible, because I want to keep it on the stack, not heap. Is that possible?

Comment: You're trying to save a reference to the stack variable k, but k is getting destroyed at the end of every loop. That's what it's complaining about.

Comment: "because I want to keep it on the stack, not heap": I cannot see how `Vec<&str>` ensures this. Each `&str` can point anywhere: stack, heap, constants...

Comment: Thanks everyone!i understood what i mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` is getting allocated on the heap regardless of how you define your Vec, the problem is the scope of `k`.

```
for i in x {
    let k = [i, p].concat();
    let q: &str = &k;
    y.push(q);
} // <- k goes out of scope at the end of each iteration.
```

`y` can not hold a reference to `k` because it will not exist when the loop finishes.

As you pointed out, `Vec<String>` will solve your issue because `String` Is an owned value, where `&str` is a borrowed one, and you are attempting to borrow from a `String` (`k`) that has a shorter lifetime than `y`.